# ORA-00904 error after granting select on a table of object

Tags: oracle

I have a problem in Oracle granting select on an object table.

When a table is created like

```
create table t (name char, ...)
```

then I don't have any problem to grant any privileges on it to any user.

But when the table is created from an object i.e.

```
create or replace 
type type_client under type_personne (
   num int ,
   username varchar(30),
   balance int,
   ta table_achat,
   ref_admin ref type_admin,

   member function get_prix_achat_total return int
);

create table t of type_client
```

I try to give select on it to a `user1` for example, but when I connect from `user1` and try to select any data from this table:

```
select * from system.table_client
```

I see the message:

> ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>   Error at Line: 1 Column: 34

Sometimes I see the message:

> Internal Error: Unknown or unimplemented accessor type: 9

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", exactly what do you mean?  Do you get an error message, and if so, what?

Comment: when i try to select some data from table
is see the message :
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 34

Comment: @user9152856 - please **[edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48022034/edit)** to show the definition of the `person` object, the actual query you're running and the error you get. It sounds like you're referencing the object fields incorrectly, rather than a privilege issue.

Comment: Not directly relevant, but you shouldn't be creating your own objects as system, or any built-in account. Create a separate user/schema for your objects.

Comment: @user9152856 - just curious, which version of Oracle are you using? (`select * from v$version` will tell you if you aren't sure)

Comment: 12c oracle (12.1.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your `Select` query is not `correct`.You can do it as below:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"

SQL> CREATE TYPE emp_type AS OBJECT (
  2    eno     NUMBER,
  3    ename   VARCHAR2(36));
  4  /

Type created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE emp_tp OF emp_type;

Table created.

SQL> GRANT SELECT on emp_tp TO system ;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect
Enter user-name: system
Enter password: ****
Connected.

SQL> show user
USER is "SYSTEM"

SQL> Select * from scott.emp_tp;--<--Make sure you put schema name before table name

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Edit:

As mentioned in my comments,the object definition is having a `member` function as well. So if you do `Select tb.get_prix_achat_total() from t tb` , it should return result. You must use column name in place of `*`when there is any fucntion in the definition.

Comment: the table table_client is created by the system...when i connect from user1 i write the query "select * from system.table_client" but the same error ...

Comment: @user9152856 Follow my steps,I clearly showed a demo..Irrespective of who creates the table, it should be able to be selected once granted. Read my full post and especially select statement,

Comment: what i mean is your code work correctly because the object and table is created by scott , so actually system can see them without any grant ..
but in my case , system create the object and table , and a normal user try to connect to table ..

Comment: i try to grant execute on type_client , but i see the same error .. !

Comment: It will work vice versa as well. But i can see problem in when you select, You object is having a member function as well. So if you do `Select tb.get_prix_achat_total() from t tb` , it should return result. What i mean to say you must use column name in place of  `*`.

Comment: yes !! you're right !!!
when i write 'select username from system.table_client'
it work !!
what is the difference in your opinion ?!

Comment: @user9152856 When you do `Select * from table` means you tell oracle to select all the columns of the table and your object is having member function as well and calling function in a select statement with `*` is not supported

Comment: Also what @Alex said, make sure not to make any objects in SYSTEM user as a good practice.

Comment: @XING - is that version-specific? I don't see a problem using `select *` in 11gR2 or 12cR2 with a similar setup, I've never seen it attempt to include the the member function. (Or do you have a doc ref?)

Comment: @AlexPoole Do you have 11g or 11gR2. I have oracle 10g and once i faced similar issue. Thats why i know this. It might be the case but am not sure. You can give a try with member function

Comment: Tested on 11gR2. I don't have a 10g DB to experiment on any more. Very interesting!

Comment: @AlexPoole I guess same you will face on Oracle 11g and that's the reason i asked about your oracle version. It would be helpful if you could experiment in 11gR2 with member function and share results. Am eager to see that as well

Comment: I don't have 11gR1 either. I ran the same demo on 11gR2, 12cR1 and 12cR2 and it was fine with `select *` on all of those. Would be interesting to know which version the OP is using. Maybe I'm still doing something slightly different - had to fill in some gaps.

Comment: i have the 12c oracle (12.1.0)
and yes i have a reference in type_client